# Make dropdown elements visible by hovering over sibling

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I have a dropdown menu structured like the code below, whose HTML code I can modify (also no adding of javascript unless can sneak it into a style tag). All buttons status-button except the "on" button should be invisible, until the "on"-button is being hovered over. Also, the search-box should always stay visible and not trigger the hover event, because that would move it down as soon as someone hovers over it -> bad UX

I successfully implemented that in CSS, but, as you can see, when you try to hover over the dropdown content they start to disappear one after another. How can I solve that?

```css
.status-menu .status-button.on {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.status-menu .status-button.on:hover ~ .status-button {
    display: block;
}

.status-menu .status-button {
    display: none;
    clear: both;
}

.status-menu .status-button:hover ~ .status-button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="status-menu">
    <a class="status-button on">...</a>
    <a class="status-button">...</a>
    <a class="status-button">...</a>
    <div class="search-container">
        <div id="search-box"><input type="text" value=""></div>
        <a id="search-button">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: You say you cannot modify the HTML. Can you add or modify javascript?

Comment: @Rounin unfortunately not, unless you know a way to snuck javascript into a style tag

Answer (score 1):

This was tricky, but if I've understood the question correctly, I am fairly sure I have cracked it.

This solution uses the `.search-container` itself to hide the two `.search-buttons`:

- a `transform: translateY()` shifts the `.search-container` upwards (ie. over the top of the second `.search-button`)
- an opaque `padding-bottom` on the `.search-container` hides the third `.search-button` immediately below it, when it is in the higher position

```css
.status-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}

.status-button {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search-container {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transform: translateY(-40px);
}

.status-button:hover ~ .search-container {
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="status-menu">
    <a class="status-button on">Status Button On</a>
    <a class="status-button">Status Button</a>
    <a class="status-button">Status Button</a>
    <div class="search-container">
        <div id="search-box"><input type="text" value=""></div>
        <a id="search-button">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your problem is not solvable with pure CSS, since the general sibling selector only looks for elements coming **after** the specified element. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) for more information about selecting siblings.

You would need a [previous sibling selecter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector), which doesn't exists. The only alternative would be to use JavaScript, if you have the possibility to add it. Here would be a working example:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('status-button');
for (i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('mouseover', showDropDown);
  links[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hideDropDown);
}
function showDropDown() {
  for (i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}
function hideDropDown() {
  for (i=1; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.status-menu .status-button:not(.on) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="status-menu">
  <a class="status-button on">...</a>
  <a class="status-button">...</a>
  <a class="status-button">...</a>
  <div class="search-container">
    <div id="search-box"><input type="text" value=""></div>
    <a id="search-button">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention a requirement. I edited my question so you can see what I also want to accomplish.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I forgot to add another important fact.